# Drop Down Menu in HTML using a Recordset

Tags: html, asp.net

I've inherited a site that I don't know much about (it's in asp.net). I'm a new programmer. I'm fairly sure this line creates a drop-down menu using information from the recordset, but I don't know exactly how it works, and I think I need to change it.

If someone could explain the inner machinations of this line, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

```
    <td colspan="2" valign="top">    <%=Replace(Application("AssetCategoryList"), "<option value=""" & objRS("CategoryID").Value & """", "<option value=""" & objRS("CategoryID").Value & """ selected</option>")%></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this is ASP.NET? it appears to be very Classic ASP-ish to me. Anyway, this line does the following operation inside of the HTML table cell:

1. Gets the value stored in the **AssetCategoryList** application variable (Global application variable in ASP.NET - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952597.aspx)

   - More than likely this contains a **string of an HTML** that defined a **Select drop-down list** - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp
2. Then, **if found** inside **AssetCategoryList**, it **Replaces** the string

   ```
   "<option value=""" & objRS("CategoryID").Value & """"
   ```

   with the string of

   ```
    "<option value=""" & objRS("CategoryID").Value & """ selected</option>"
   ```

   - Now the **objRS("CategoryID")** will become data found in the **CategoryID** field for this **Row** of the **Recordset** object
   - And of course the same goes for the 2nd CategoryID
3. You should note that the difference between these two option tags is the **selected** attribute, which will cause this option in the select (drop-down list) to be pre-selected - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

If you want to see the actual value inside the AssetCategoryList application variable is (to better understand this operation), then simply add some markup and code to the top of the content of this page like:

```
 <%  
 Response.Write(Application("AssetCategoryList")) 
 Response.End 
 %>
```